re match text enclosed in { } where text may contain {{var}}
I'm trying to create a regular expression to match a pattern of the form:
content = "identifier{ {{var1}} rest of the content} outer content identifier{ {{var2}} another content} identifier{ content with no vars }"

so supposedly I run re.findall on content the return value should be:
["{{var1}} rest of the content", "{{var2}} another content", "content with no vars"]

the pattern I want to match is identifier\{.*?\} but I don't know how to make it work as the enclosing pattern is included in the text I want to match so it either matches before the required place when I make it stingy, or it will merge the two patterns with each other when greedy, which is something I don't want.

What pattern are you using?

identifier{.*?} I mentioned it in the post, sorry if it was not clear from the post, but I cannot settle on a pattern as it either will merge the two expressions or it will return two partial expressions.

But what good does that do?  You're not checking for the curly braces at all.  You are matching 0 or more characters, optionally.

Do you have to use a regular expression? You could simply iterate over the text keeping a running count of open brackets and yield a result when the count returns to zero

If you want to allow multiple occurrences of {{var}} and not allow any other curly's:
{([^{}]*(?:{{[^{}]*}}[^{}]*)*)}

The pattern matches:

{ Match literally
( Capture group 1

[^{}]* Match optional chars other than { and }
(?: Non capture group

{{ Match literally
[^{}]* atch optional chars other than { and }
}} Match literally
[^{}]* Match optional chars other than { and }


)* Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it


) Close group 1
} Match literally

Regex demo
To remove the leading and trailing whitespace you can use strip:
import re

pattern = r"{([^{}]*(?:{{[^{}]*}}[^{}]*)*)}"
content = "identifier{ {{var1}} rest of the content} outer content identifier{ {{var2}} another content} identifier{ content with no vars }"

print([s.strip() for s in re.findall(pattern, content)])

Output
['{{var1}} rest of the content', '{{var2}} another content', 'content with no vars']


If you want the capture group values without the surrounding whitespaces, and allow only a single opening and closing curly, you can use non greedy quantifiers with negative lookarounds:
(?<!{){\s*([^{}]*?(?:{{[^{}]+}}[^{}]*?)*)\s*}(?!})

Regex demo

To expand on my comment to Tim's reply, I might have used the VERBOSE flag, (re.X),  to more clearly show the regex.
import re

s = "identifier{ {{var1}} rest of the content} outer content identifier{ {{var2}} another content} identifier{ content with no vars }"
pat = re.compile(r'''{\s+
                 (                    # begin capture group
                    (?:               # optional 'var' with enclosing braces
                        {{[^}]+}}
                    )?  
                    [^}]+             # 'content'
                 )                    # end capture group''', re.X)
L = re.findall(pat, s)


print(L)

Prints:
['{{var1}} rest of the content', '{{var2}} another content', 'content with no vars ']


You may match the regular expression
(?<=identifier{ ).*?(?<!})(?= *}(?!}))

Regex demo | Python demo
The expression can be broken down as follows.
(?<=identifier{ ) # positive lookbehind asserts that the match               
                  # is preceded by 'identifier{ '
.*?               # match zero or more characters other than
                  # line terminators, as few as possible
(?<!})            # negative lookbehind asserts last character
                  # is not '}'
(?=               # begin a positive lookahead
   *}             # match zero or more spaces followed by '}'
  (?!})           # negative lookahead asserts that the 
                  # preceding '}' is not followed by '}'
)                 # end positive lookahead

If the word 'identifier' is not required to immediately precede '{ ', remove 'identifier' from the lookbehind:
(?<={ ).*?(?<!})(?= *}(?!}))


This does what you asked:
import re
content = "identifier{ {{var1}} rest of the content} outer content identifier{ {{var2}} another content}"

f = re.compile(r'{\s*({{[^}]*}}[^}]*)}')
print(f.findall(content))

Output:
['{{var1}} rest of the content', '{{var2}} another content']

Explaining the regex, it's "curly brace followed by spaces, then capture two curly braces followed by anything that's not a closed brace, followed by two curly braces, then anything that's not a closed brace".

thanks, but can this pattern also include the case where the content doesn't contain {{var}} at all, I just updated the post with the new details, I'm really sorry for not mentioning that.

@ntriisii After adding a grouping parenthesis for the enclosed 'var' to Tim's regex, the result you are looking for can be captured.  r'{\s*((?:{{[^}]}})?[^}])}'.
